# EC2 S3 connection

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been able to successfully setup and run my EC2 instance after uploading my files to the instance.  I have two questions regarding the security of the files which reside in my EC2 instance during this time.  I of course have a private key when I SSH into my instance.

1) Is there a way to avoid uploading to my EC2 instance and directly have EC2 use my S3 bucket contents through the AWS CLI?

2) Any suggestions regarding securing the files while they reside in the EC2 instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use AWS CLI to do this. `aws s3api getobject` command would do job for you.
But you need to have an IAM role attached to your ec2 instance and that IAM role should have sufficient s3 permissions.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html

You can secure the files in ec2 instance (assuming it is linux isntance), by restricting file permissions to users. Refer to this link to understand more about how File permissions works: https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html

Comment: See also: [Using High-Level s3 Commands with the AWS Command Line Interface - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)